# Como executar o cmake usando o MSYS2 sem ter que configurar variável de ambiente no Windows

Tags: cmake, msys2

Estou tentando usar o cmake para compilar um projeto escrito em C++, o projeto compila sem problemas se eu usar uma IDE (testado no Qt Creator e CLion), mas preciso compilar por linha de comando, pois estou configurar o ambiente para uma compilação remota.

```
D:\Workspace\analytics>cmake . -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="C:\msys32\mingw32" -B build
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: D:/Workspace/analytics/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/mingw32-make.exe cmTC_53d35/fast
    C:/msys32/mingw32/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_53d35.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_53d35.dir/build
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'D:/Workspace/analytics/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_53d35.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
    C:\msys32\mingw32\bin\gcc.exe    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_53d35.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj   -c D:\Workspace\analytics\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\cmTC_53d35.dir\build.make:65: CMakeFiles/cmTC_53d35.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 1
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/Workspace/analytics/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:120: cmTC_53d35/fast] Error 2




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/Workspace/analytics/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "D:/Workspace/analytics/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

- Se eu configurar no PATH do Windows o caminho MinGW
  "C:/msys32/mingw32/bin" o comando de compilação funciona, reconhece o compilador e etc...,  porém as IDE começam a dar erro.
- Se eu entrar pelo console do MSYS2 eu consigo compilar sem problemas
  também

Estou tentando compilar o projeto usando o cmd do Windows

```
cmake . -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="C:\msys32\mingw32" -B build
```

Tentei passar o caminho do compilador gcc e g++

```
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=C:\msys32\mingw32\bin\gcc.exe
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=C:\msys32\mingw32\bin\g++.exe
```

Porém não tive sucesso também.

Como eu posso chamar o cmake por linha de comando usando MinGW do MSYS2 para compilar o projeto sem ter que configurar no PATH do Windows o caminho do MinGW?

Answer (score 0):

Crie um cmd para rodar o cmake:

call_cmake.cmd

```
@echo off

:: nao exporta as variaveis de ambiente para o cmd externo
setlocal

set PATH=path_gcc_mingw;%PATH%

:: chama cmake...

:: etc
```

Para compilar, mesma coisa:

make_proj.cmd

```
@echo off

:: nao exporta as variaveis de ambiente para o cmd externo
setlocal

set PATH=path_gcc_mingw;%PATH%

make

:: etc
```